# set netbeans output into a Text Area

Tags: netbeans, textarea, output

Well, the issue is that I have 1 main class with all methods inside (wasn't me) & I had to create a GUI, the app works fine in the console but i dunno how to set all that comes from the ouput window into the textArea having it in case of log error, I need to know how to show whatever output console shows into a textArea.

[image: Output Window]

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific on your requirements? Try posting some source code and point out the trouble.

Comment: for example, i've the method comparaitve(); & it was inserted in a Comparative btn & when i excute it from GUI or click it, it shows me everything that it's doing in the output window, all the logic it's want i want to show.